# Creating a balanced bidirectional pulse pair, also called the Lilly Wave and change it's sample amounts in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

Greetings I'm tying to create a bidirectional pulse pair, or the Lilly Wave (Lilly wave)  using Octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab.

This is what I found out about a Lilly wave
[Lilly wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Lilly)

[image: Lilly wave image]

> The previous wave forms used in neurophysiology and in neurosurgery
>   injured the neurons when unidirectional current passed through the
>   brain. Dr. Lilly developed a new electrical wave form to balance the
>   current, first in one direction and then, after a brief interval, in
>   the other. Thus ions moving in the neurons would first be pushed one
>   way and then quickly the other way, stimulating the neurons and
>   leaving the ions in their former positions within the neurons. This
>   new wave form was called a balanced bidirectional pulse pair, or the
>   Lilly Wave. Microscopic studies of brains stimulated with this
>   balanced pulse pair showed that there was no injury of the neuronal
>   networks from this kind Waveform of stimulating current: pulse pairs
>   of current resulting from quasi-differentiation, with passive
>   electrical elements, of a rectangular pulse. Measured at 2 percent of
>   the peak, the duration of the positive pulse (upward) is 34 sec, and
>   the duration of the negative pulse (downward) is 28 sec. stimulation.

I have two questions:
1) Is this the best way to create a "lilly wave" for export to an audio source?
2) How do I get the signal to be 44100 samples instead of 154350 samples.

Code below:

```
clear all
graphics_toolkit gnuplot %use this for now it's older but allows zoom
figure
clf
% SCRIPT BEGINS
t=linspace(0,1,44100);
freq=1; %how many in 1 sec
A = 1; % amplitude
T = 1/freq; % period of the signal

%sine wave
ysin=sin(2*pi*freq*t);

square=0*t;

lilly=[ysin(1:length(t)/2),square(1:length(t)/2),-ysin(1:length(t)/2),square,square];
figure;
plot(lilly)
```

[image: Plot of lilly wave]

Comment: This question is off topic, because it is not a programming question. The important point to answer this question: How is a lilly wave defined? That requires some research on the mathematical background.

Comment: @Daniel  Ok I'll post it to the mathematical section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to point 2).

The pulses have tails, like gaussians

```
# a simple gaussian
gauss = @(t, t0, g) exp(-((t-t0)/g).^2);

# sampling
t=0:1:44100;

# pulses peak positions (s)
t1 = 10000; 
t2 = 30000; 
# pulses width (at 1/e^2) (s)
g = 2000;

lilly = gauss(t, t1, g) - gauss(t, t2, g);

plot(t, lilly)
```

which yields
[image]